# How to set http status code 200, 400, 422, 202 set as success in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I want to mark all the response with, http status code 200, 400, 422, 202 set as success.

Is there any way I can achieve this in a single assertion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also include what you have tried so far, to resolve this it is very simple,

Need to include a JSR223 assertion with the following script,

```
if("400".equals(SampleResult.getResponseCode()) || "200".equals(SampleResult.getResponseCode()) || "202".equals(SampleResult.getResponseCode()) || "422".equals(SampleResult.getResponseCode())) { 
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true); 
    AssertionResult.setFailure(false); 
} 
else {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be with a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

Add the [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)  into the Test Plan. This will ensure the Assertion is applied to all the Samplers (Responses)

[image]

Then configure the [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

1. `Field to Test` as `Response Code`
2. Pattern matching rules to `Equals` and `Or`
3. Click the `Add` button and add the response codes

[image]

In addition to the above configuration, you may check the `Ignore Status` if you want to `Instructs JMeter to set the status to success initially.`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution based on the previous answer.

```
//Expected Response codes
def lstExpectedResponseCodes= ["400", "200", "202","422"]

//Actual Response code 
String actualResponseCode=SampleResult.getResponseCode()

boolean hasResponseCode = lstExpectedResponseCodes.contains(actualResponseCode)

AssertionResult.setFailure(!hasResponseCode)
SampleResult.setSuccessful(hasResponseCode);
```